# How can I introduce a non-generalized proposition that is part of a conjunction in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have a goal of the form `exists x:nat, (P /\ Q)`, but in the hypotheses, `P` is not generalized. Is it possible to prove this using `revert` or `generalize`? For example, to prove this:

```
Fact inject_prop: forall(P Q: Prop), P /\ (exists x:nat, Q )-> exists x:nat, (P /\ Q).
Admitted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposition can be easily proved:

```
Fact inject_prop:
  forall(P Q: Prop), P /\ (exists x:nat, Q )-> exists x:nat, (P /\ Q).
Proof.
intros P Q [HP [x HQ]]. exists 0. split; eauto.
Qed.
```

However, I suspect that you might have meant to put something slightly different: `P` and `Q` in your example have no relation to the existentially quantified natural number (note that in my proof I have said `exists 0` instead of `exists x`).

Comment: Thanks. You were right about Q having no relation to the the existentially quantified number. The proof I was looking for was as you suggested:

`Fact inject_prop2: forall(P : Prop) (Q: nat -> Prop) , P /\ (exists x:nat, Q(x) )-> exists x:nat, (P /\ Q(x)). Proof. intros P Q [HP [x HQ]]. exists x. split; eauto. Qed.`